# WPF binding a dependency property to a datatrigger's setter value in a Custom Control

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a simple custom control which changes its content property based on a bool value. And it seems that for some reason i cannot reach a depenency property on my custom control to bind it. Here is my existing code:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:EditableTextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:EditableTextBlock}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel>

                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ContentControl"
                                       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=InEditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                                    
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=InEditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:EitableTextBlock}}}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see I use two type of Binding:

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:EitableTextBlock}}}
```

And it works fine in the datatrigger Binding section, but both of the above binding fails to  bind my Text property which is registered in the code-behind, which is weird because the "InEditMode" bool property works fine and can be bind to.

So my question is: Why can't I bind a registered dependency property in a datatrigger's setter section, but can bind in datatrigger "Binding" attribute?

Any help would be appriciated!